# How to handle SSL Certificate for Edge browser in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge

We have requirement to run automation test in Edge browser using protractor. I am able to lunch Edge through protector after gone through some references but now I am stuck in handling the SSL Certificate for Edge. Not getting any proper reference how to do this in Protractor.

It will be really help if any one can share any reference.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal scenario here is to avoid using SSL during testing.

Generally, SSL termination is best handled by your outward facing webserver, rather than within your application. This has numerous advantages:

- It makes developing and debugging your application easier
- It makes testing easier, as you are seeing
- It removes the overhead of SSL handshakes

I appreciate that you may not have control over this, or you might be testing something which requires SSL (you should probably move it into its own suite and find an alternative method of testing it), but that's the ideal.

If you're still stuck, I'd look at going into more detail about your problem - as you don't exactly specify what the problem you are encountering is, just that you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Due to requirement I can't skip the SSL certification but I manage to handle it. Just added this 'acceptInsecureCerts': true, and it started working.